# PySide/QT - How to add horizontal or vertical layout to a grid layout

Tags: grid, pyqt4, pyside, python-3.3

If I wanted to create a window where a grid layout didn't cover the whole frame? Could I do it by adding a horizontal layout to the grid layout and adding a stretch to the horizontal layout. When I try it in the following code, I get this error:

> TypeError: PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addLayout(): not enough arguments

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        names = ['Cls', 'Bck', '', 'Close', '7', '8', '9', '/',
                '4', '5', '6', '*', '1', '2', '3', '-',
                '0', '.', '=', '+']

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch()

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch()
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addLayout(vbox)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.move(300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator')
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This error does not occur when adding a horizontal layout to a vertical layout or vice versa.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the layout to a `QGridLayout` at a specific row and column according to the method signature [here](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGridLayout.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.addLayout).

But in this case, I think you are better off adding the grid layout to the vbox layout, not vice versa

Or, you could set a column stretch for an empty column in the grid layout using [QGridLayout.setColumnStretch()](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGridLayout.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGridLayout.setColumnStretch).